# Laravel - ограничить количис во символов при выводе из базы данных

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

`$post ['post_title']`

как тут ограничить количество символов для вывода?

Comment: Интересует непосредственно изменение переменной `$post` или же вывод для `echo`?

Comment: Ну вот я в макете вывожу через $post ['post_title'] - это заголовок статьи выводится и если длинное название как ограничить?

Comment: Помимо `Str::limit` можете посмотреть [`Str:words`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-str-words)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать метод [`Str::limit`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-str-limit):

```php
<!-- The quick brown fox... -->
{{ Str::limit($post['post_title'], 20) }}
```

Третьим аргументом Вы можете передать строку, которая будет добавлена в конец:

```php
<!-- The quick brown fox (...) -->
{{ Str::limit($post['post_title'], 20, ' (...)') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно стилями "обрезать". Как-то так:

```
<h1 style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">Длинный заголовок, очень длинный, ... и так далее</h1>
```

Если используете Tailwind, то ([Text Overflow](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/text-overflow)):

```
<p class="truncate ...">...</p>
```